# Run a remote command on all Jenkins slaves via Masters's script console

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I want to run same shell command (very simple shell commands like `ls`) on all the UNIX slaves 
which are connected to the master by using the master's script console.

How can I do this using groovy?

Want to do something like this: [Display Information About Nodes](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Display+Information+About+Nodes)
but instead of displaying information, I want to also run some simple UNIX commands on each slave and print the results.

Comment: Why do you need it? It seems more like an orchestration role, like puppet and salt does.

Comment: Yes I am looking for something like what puppet does but in Jenkins.

Comment: What about using jenkins with rundeck or even puppet? What's the problem you wanna solve? Doesn't seem practical to me to use jenkins in this way, seems like misusing, what do you think?

Comment: Actually my main reason is to see if this is possible via groovy system script. I am almost sure this can be done this way (though could be a misuse).

Comment: Maybe I should consider using Puppet Labs or Chef Software plug-ins. :-)

Comment: http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Execute-a-command-on-all-nodes-master-slaves-td4024223.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
import hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics;

print_ip = 'println InetAddress.localHost.hostAddress';
print_hostname = 'println InetAddress.localHost.canonicalHostName';

// here it is - the shell command, uname as example 
uname = 'def proc = "uname -a".execute(); proc.waitFor(); println proc.in.text';

for (slave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
    println slave.name;
    println RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(print_ip, slave.getChannel());
    println RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(print_hostname, slave.getChannel());
    println RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(uname, slave.getChannel());
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it works for some commands but any command with a * in it doesn't seem to execute. Any ideas on that? I tried escaping it but that just got a error.

Comment: @timmyonline i combine a lot from this blog https://onekilo79.wordpress.com/2016/03/31/jenkins-console-script-with-power/ to really make it work

Comment: A few more examples here https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-console/#run-scripts-from-controller-script-console-on-agents

Answer (score 1):

Until the end, I don't use  *  to search the agents, but instead I'm reading and parsing their names. For example, if I want to run a job on every agent that has LINUX in name, I will do next:

```
for (aSlave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves)
{
   /* take into account just agents with LINUX in name*/
   AGENT_NAME = aSlave.name
   if ( AGENT_NAME.contains('LINUX') )
   {
      /* you can check also if the agent is online or other attributes */

      /* Add agent name as label of the agent */ 
      AGENT_LABELS = aSlave.getLabelString() + " " + AGENT_NAME
      aSlave.setLabelString(AGENT_LABELS)


      /* For each found agent, create a job that will run on it */
      job('My_job_name_' + AGENT_NAME)
      {
          label(AGENT_NAME)
          steps {
               /* Do whatever you want here. 
                  This job will run just on this specific agent (due to label set) */
           }
      } 
   } /* end if */
} /* end for */  

/* If you want to run all jobs in parallel (every job on a specific agent), you can save all found agents in a list and then create one more pipeline job that will contain next line :

   ' parallel {
      b0: {build 'My_job_name_' + AGENT_NAME_LIST[0]},
      b1: {build 'My_job_name_' + AGENT_NAME_LIST[1]},
      ....
    }
    fastfail: false '
```

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline looks something like this:

```
stages  {
      stage('Checkout repo') {
         steps  {
            //checkout what I need
         }
      }
      stage('Generate Jobs')  {
         steps  {
            jobDsl targets:'generate_projects.groovy',
         }
      }
      stage('Build Projects')  {
         steps  {
            build job: "build-all",
            propagate: true,
            wait: true
         }
      }
   }
```

and then is file generate_projects.groovy, where the actually DSL generation is:

```
for (agent in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
   if (!agent.getComputer().isOffline())  { // check that agent is not offline
      node = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getNode(agent.name)  // get agent name
      agentIPs = node.computer.getChannel().call(new ListPossibleNames())
      agentIP = agentIPs[0]  // get agent IP
      
      //Create a job that will run on that specific agent
      jobName = FOLDER + '/<Job_name>' + agent.name     // need to create different names
      job(jobName)
      {
         label(agent.name)
         steps
         {
             shell(<shell script or commands that you want to run>)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Beside the above generation of the jobs, you'll need to keep a list of jobs that were generated and add all its elements in "build-all" pipeline job, that will look something like:

```
parallel(
   b0: {build '<Job_name>' + agent.name'},
   b1: {build '<Job_name>' + agent.name'},
   b2: {build '<Job_name>' + agent.name'},
   .....
)
failFast: false
```

So when you run the pipeline, a job for each agent will be created, and all new created jobs will run in parallel. I use it for updating setup scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old thread.

I managed the same situation in next way. I have a pipeline jobs that is doing next stages:
 - first it checks online agents (since they are physical machine it may happen to be down) using something like: for "(slave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves)..."
 - next stage is to create jobs for each found agent using DSL plugin and list_of_agents.each.
Besides jobs for every online agent, it's created a job that will run all of them in parallel. Of course, the new created jobs contains the commands that I want to run on agents. When I run the pipeline, on all agents will run the same script/commands and output is returned to master pipeline job.

Comment: It would be useful to add any code you used to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use pipes or chain commands this is another solution: (as suggested by Graeme in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583979/run-a-remote-command-on-all-jenkins-slaves-via-masterss-script-console#comment86508879_27700721) )

```
import hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics;

def executeCmd(slave, cmd){
  process = "new ProcessBuilder( 'sh', '-c', \"$cmd\").redirectErrorStream(true).start()"
  script = "def proc = $process; proc.waitFor(); println proc.in.text";
  try{
    return RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(script, slave.getChannel());
  } catch(Exception e){
    return "EXCEPTION:"+e.getMessage();
  }
}

remote_cmd="pwd | xargs ls -ld"
for (slave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
  println slave.name  
  println executeCmd(slave, remote_cmd);
}
```