# How to SSH into jenkins host executing code

Tags: maven, jenkins, build, continuous-integration, hudson

I have a jenkins job set up and I'm having some issues getting around my company's proxy. I'd like to SSH into the jenkins slave executing this job.

Where could I find the host name in jenkins?

So I can add the proper proxy into the settings.xml file. It should be located {home}/.m2/settings.xml

Comment: Surely you'd want to add these settings to *all* slaves, not just one?

Comment: Just one, for some reason only my particular job isn't running. No idea why? I am assuming proxy is the problem but I'm not sure until I can actually get into the box and see

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583979/run-a-remote-command-on-all-jenkins-slaves-via-masterss-script-console). Running this groovy script on jenkins script console will list the slaves and their ip address.

```
import hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics;

print_ip = 'println InetAddress.localHost.hostAddress';
print_hostname = 'println InetAddress.localHost.canonicalHostName';

// here it is - the shell command, uname as example 
uname = 'def proc = "uname -a".execute(); proc.waitFor(); println proc.in.text';

for (slave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
    println slave.name;
    println RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(print_ip, slave.getChannel());
}
```

Comment: This is far too much work for something as simple as getting a host name to ssh

Comment: the executeGroovy command will only work when the slave is connected and therefore the getChannel() command is non null. use this: if (slave.getChannel()) {...}

Answer (score -1):

```
Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes
```

Comment: Please consider adding more detail to your answer.

Comment: The question is: "Where could I find the host name in jenkins?" The poster wants to know how to find the slaves on the jenkins server. Going to "Manage Jenkins" and then to "Manage Nodes" will show all the slaves on the jenkins server.

The notation I have used is the common way to describe using a menu option and a sub menu option.