# How to reboot Jenkins node using shell in Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am writing a Groovy script to perform an automatic reboot of Windows servers. In the script, I am first taking the nodes offline, then checking to see if there are any builds, if there aren't, then perform a restart.

I wanted to use the safeRestart() method but it doesn't support the import statement I am using when looping through the nodes.  I have seen an execute() method which basically executes a shell line of code in groovy.

How would I execute a restart of the Windows computers using execute()?

Comment: I assume these are Windows Jenkins Nodes. How are you launching them ? java Web Start or from master ? Is the Jenkins user an Admin on the windows server ?

Comment: @IanW Yes, these are Windows Jenkins Nodes.  They are launched from the master node.  And yes, the user is an admin.  But how would it make a difference if the user is an admin on the windows server?

Comment: Anyone can launch via Java web start and if you're not an admin on the server, you should not be able to restart the server. Hence the inquiry.

Comment: @IanW I see.  So is there a way to restart the server in Groovy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will answer your question directly, but will point in the right direction ...

You can leverage this S/O question: [Run a remote command on all Jenkins slaves via Masters's script console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26583979/598141) or this Gist: [run_command_on_all_slaves.groovy](https://gist.github.com/hfs/68b2f124d1952233ba49)

btw: Jenkins API does seem to support running a [script directly](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Computer.html#doScriptText-org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest-org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerResponse-) on the server ([Computer](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Computer.html)).

Your actual command should be [`shutdown /r`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown)`

I don't believe you can do this unless the Node is on-line. Disconnecting the node stops the Jenkins slave process, then there's nothing running on the node, so not sure what control you'd have. Instead you want to block the queue and let the existing jobs finish:

```
Jenkins.instance.getNode('Node-Name').toComputer().setAcceptingTasks(false)
```

and check:

```
Jenkins.instance.getNode('Node-Name').toComputer().countBusy() == 0
```

Then run your (work on server) restart command

When the server is available again, launch the node and open the queue.

```
Jenkins.instance.getNode('Node-Name').getComputer().launch()
Jenkins.instance.getNode('Node-Name').getComputer().setAcceptingTasks(true)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: To reiterate, I cannot set the node temporarily offline because it won't run the build to restart the node?  Also, regarding actually restarting the computer, what should be the groovy syntax to do this? I know that I need to use .execute() but I'm not sure how?

Comment: What would be the exact restart command in Groovy? And how would I know the server is available again?